# AJAX code not updating table

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Here is my form, from which i want to update the values. When i try this with simple php+html it works perfectly!! But when i try to post values through ajax call it doesn't work.Any suggestions please.

**HTML**

```
<form class="form-block" role="form" action="" method="post">
 <div class="form-group">
 <?php
 $email=$_SESSION["login_email"];
 $query=mysqli_query($con,"select * from customers where email='$email'");
 while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
 ?>
<label for="name">Full Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" class="form-control"   id="name" value="<?= $row["name"]; ?>" placeholder="Full Name">
 <label for="comment">Address</label>
 <textarea class="form-control" name="address" id="address" rows="5" id="comment"  ></textarea>
<label for="telephone">Telephone</label>
<input type="tel" class="form-control" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Enter Mobile Number" value="" >
  <label for="city">City</label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="city" id="city" placeholder="Enter City" value="<?= $row["city"]; ?>" >
  </div>
 <?php
}?>
 <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="add" id="add" value="Update"/>


<span class='msg'></span>
   <div id="error"></div>
   </form>
```

**AJAX**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
$('#add').click(function()
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: "address_update.php",
                type: "POST",
                async: true,
                data: { Name:$("#name").val(),Address:$("#address").val(), Phone:$("#phone").val(), City:$("#city").val()}, //your form data to post goes here as a json object
                dataType: "html",

                success: function(data) {
                    if(data)
                    {
                        //$('#output').html(data);
                        $("body").load("index.php?page=form");//.hide();//.fadeIn(1500).delay(6000);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $("#error").html("<span style='color:#cc0000'>Error:</span> Invalid username and password. ");
                    }}});
        });});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
include ("db/db.php");
session_start();

$name=$_POST['Name'];
    $address=$_POST['Address'];
    $phone=$_POST['Phone'];
    $city=$_POST['City'];
$email=$_SESSION['login_email'];

$sql=mysqli_query($con,"Update customers set name='$name',address='$address',phone='$phone',city='$city' where email='$email'");
    if($sql)
    {
echo "updated";
    }
```

Comment: @Saty it doesn't make any difference. Problem is in AJAX call

Comment: Also, the `.load` controller is deprecated now, you'd have to use another AJAX call

Comment: also use `$_POST['Name']` instead `$_POST['name']` and soo onn...

Comment: Well updated my question still ajax isn't working..

Comment: any errors in the console?

Answer (score 3):

This selector:

```
$('#add')
```

doesn't find anything.  Because there is no HTML element in your markup with `id="add"`.

You *do* have an element with `name="add"`.  So either add an `id` to that element:

```
<input id="add" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="add" value="Update"/>
```

or change your selector to target the existing element:

```
$('input[name="add"]')
```

---

Note: The same is also true of `$('#address')` and `$('#phone')`.  No such elements exist in your markup.  Take a look at [the jQuery documentation for selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Comment: Corrected it!! But still doesn't make any difference. Have a look at the updated question

Comment: @tabia: How specifically is this failing?  When you debug this, what happens?  Is the event handler added to the element?  Is the handler invoked when you click the element?  Is the AJAX request made?  What is the server's response?  Are there any errors on the JavaScript console?  We can't see what's happening in your browser, but you can.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the IF loop mentioned under

```
if(isset($_SESSION["login_email"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you nee to change the button type from submit to button

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="add" value="Update"/>
```

Above sends the form, whatever you add to the click event is done in parralel.

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-default" name="add" value="Update"/>
```

only executes your JavaScript, when using:

```
 $('input [name="add"]').click(function(){
   // your improved ajax call here
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    .
    .
    data: {
    'Name': $name,
    'address': $address,
    .
    .
}
});
```